# How to find Price Tag with Dollar Sign, thousand delimiter AND decimal point by Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to parse out the "**$1000.00**" in one piece (string) from the following string:

"*lost a bookcase ($1,000.00) after waiting for nearly three months.*"

How should I design my regex pattern in re.findall() function? Thanks!

What I have tried is `re.findall(r"\d+[.,]?\d+", text)` and I only got:
['1,000', '00']

However, I wanted my output to be is: 
['$1,000.00']

Comment: Looks like a straightforward question to someone who learned the basics of regular expressions. What have you tried?

Comment: Please post a clear input and desired output samples.

Comment: I want Input: re.findall(*Regex Pattern*, "lost a bookcase ($1,000.00) after waiting for nearly three months.") 
Output: $1000.00

@PedroLobito

Comment: @DYZ I have successfully parsed out the 1000 and 000.000 separately

Comment: But what was your regular expression?

Comment: @DYZ I have got ```\d+[.,]?\d+```, But it only gives me ['1000','00'], not '$1000.00' as one piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to find Price Tag with Dollar Sign, thousand delimiter AND decimal
>   point by Python Regex

---

[money_parser egg](https://pypi.org/project/money-parser/) is exactly what you need:

**Installation:**

```
pip install money_parser
```

---

**Usage:**

```
from money_parser import price_str
x = "lost a bookcase ($1,000.00) after waiting for nearly three months."
print(price_str(x))
# 1000.00
```

---

## Old Answer

You can use something like:

```
x = "lost a bookcase ($1,000.00) after waiting for nearly three months."
result =  re.findall(r"\b\$?[\d,.]+\b", x)
```

---

`['1,000.00']`

---

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nJDAxp/1)**
**[Python Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/Qmf)**

---

**Regex Explanation**
[image]

---

Notes:

1. Not a *bullet-proof* regex `\b\$?[\d,.]+\b`, but enough to get you
   started.
2. *Regexes* used by money_parser:

---

```
_CLEANED_PRICE_RE = re.compile('[+-]?(?:\d{1,3}[.,]?)+')
_FRACTIONAL_PRICE_RE = re.compile('^([\d.,]+)[.,](\d{1,2})$')
```

Comment: This is perfect. Can you explain that why the dollar sign $ was not captured?

Comment: Refer to [money_parser documentation](https://pypi.org/project/money-parser/) for more details. If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: The Money Money Parser probabaly won't work for me as my final goal is to parse the whole sentence into a list of strings while maintain the "$1,000.00" as one piece. The optimal final output should be: 

```["lost", "a", "bookcase", "(", "$1,000.00", ")", "after", "waiting", "for", "nearly", "three", "months", "."]```

Do you know how to parse the sentence into this format? Thanks!   
@PedroLobito

Comment: Not exactly in this format, but you can try a simple `x.split()`, which will give you `['lost', 'a', 'bookcase', '($1,000.00)', 'after', 'waiting', 'for', 'nearly', 'three', 'months.']`

Comment: Thanks, this way also won't work as I need to separate things like "(" and "." to be its own string as well. For the money part, I only need to worry about the "$". I don't have to consider any other currency label.

@PedroLobito

Comment: Thanks for your help! @PedroLobito